# PHP Coding styles return; in switch/case

Tags: php, coding-style

we're trying to implement new coding style guidelines for our team, the php codesniffer is printing an warning on switch case statements when no "break" is found like:

```
switch ($foo) {   
    case 1:
      return 1;   
    case 2:
      return 2;   
   default:
       return 3; 
}
```

is there any good reason to use :

```
   switch ($foo) {
       case 1:
         return 1;
         break;
   }
```

?? the break is never reached ?

Comment: I'd suggest making the @category question a separate question, since it's unrelated.

Comment: Maybe codesniffer is just wrong and doesn’t check for `return` but only for `break`.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to leave out the `break` when you `return` from a `switch`.

But it's fairly common practise to add explicit `break`s to every `case` as a [defensive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) practise.

```
switch ($foo) {
    case 1:
        return 1;
        break;

    case 2:
        return 2;
        break;
}
```

The idea is that should you later change your code in `case 1` and remove the return statement, you could forget to add a `break`.

That would accidentally cause program flow to fall through to `case 2`.

```
switch ($foo) {
    case 1:
        somethingDifferent();

    case 2:
        return 2;
        break;
}
```

Falling through case statements is slightly unusual and you should add a comment to your code when you do it to show that it's intentional.

```
switch ($foo) {
    case 1:
        somethingDifferentAndWeWantToDoCase2AsWell();
        // fallthrough

    case 2:
        return 2;
        break;
}
```

As with many defensive programming practises you've got to balance whether the code bloat - which potentially clutters your code and make it less readable - is worth it or not.

Answer (score 12):

If your "php codesniffer is printing a warning" try to get another better codesniffer and don't forget to try to use the last PHP stable version. You can, of course, write a `break`after one `return`, but it doesn't make sense, because it will never be read at all. Your code is OK.

Look at this:

```
$fun = function(int $argument): string {
    switch ($argument) {
        case 1:
            return "one";
        case 2:
            return "two";
        default:
            return "more than two";
    }
};
$str = $fun(4); // return "more than two"
```

In my opinion, this is simpler and better: fewer lines => less code to maintain :-)

Answer (score 8):

To answer your question, no there's no good reason to have something that does nothing. Think about it this way, a comment after the `return` instead of a `break` saying "don't forget" will have the same affect - none. And put that way it sounds silly, right?

Unless you need to set a var to use later, I'd suggest the approach you have is perfectly fine. I knew the code's intent within 2 seconds from looking at it. Having a `break` just creates confusion.

There is no one size fits all really. The correct approach depends on whichever fits the scenario. Set a variable in each `case` and having a `break` may be the right way, or perhaps just return makes sense.

---

Some observations on other suggestions made in answers:

**1)** *Not having a `break` after `return` means problems could arise if code is later changed*

Whenever possible, code should be explicit, as well as readable and clear. We can also code in a way to make future changes easier. But in something as simple as a `switch` it should be no problem and need no safety net to refactor a `case` later to add or remove a `return` or `break`.

In fact, if you removed a `return` and "*didn't notice there was no `break`*" then that's a poor mistake and could be made in any part of coding. No gotcha checking will save you from that. And one should be very careful coding for future potentials, as that potential may never happen, or something else may happen, and you just end up maintaining obsolete code for years.

In the same vein this was argued to be a safety net for future changes - What if you remove the `return` and accidentally left in that safety net `break` when you should have removed it?

Even if this switch statement was a life or death scenario, really serious code, I would be against adding the "pointless" break after the return. Just make sure whoever was working on the code knew what they were doing, and it was code reviewed by enough eyes and tested fully.
If it was that serious, then you'd have additional checks in place better than a proposed safety net to catch sloppy devs.

To argue that break after return adds a safety net, means you're not coding or testing properly. If this is a safety net deemed useful then it's likely there are tons of bugs in the code in potentially more serious places.

The wiki article of "Defensive Programming" was linked to, but it's not relevant here:

> Defensive programming is a form of defensive design intended to ensure
>   the continuing function of a piece of software under unforeseen
>   circumstances.

Leaving a safety net `break` in is not a scenario of unforeseen circumstances, nor defensive programming. It's just bad coding, **and you can't litter your code with back up code just in case you don't code correctly when you change something**. That's such a bad approach to coding. The argument that "if someone removed return it won't work", well you could also have a typo in the case var, or forget to write the case, or...

The `return` returns, and you don't code "defensively" to avoid a return failing. That would mean PHP is broken, and you aint gonna fill your code with safety nets to cater for that. That's something you have on a much higher level up.

**2)** *`break` after `return` keeps it explicit*

But it's explicitly wrong. The `return` returns, so the break won't happen. To me that is scratch head time wondering if I've missed the intent - not for long as it's clear what *will* happen, but there will be a moment where I ponder it to make sure I've not missed something.

While it's not invalid or error to have a `return` and then `break` in the same `case`, it's just entirely pointless as the `break` does nothing. It's pointless code that needs to be seen, maintained, and figured out as it's not logical.

If *explicit* is the core goal *and* having a `break` after a `return` urks you because it's pointless, then I'd say it'd be better to set a variable and `break`, then return the variable after breaking from the switch.
Like @RageZ answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1437476/2632129

**3)** *Set a variable and return after the switch statement is completed*

There's nothing wrong with this approach at all, but if there's no reason to store the value in a variable (later use etc) then it's good to return immediately when there's no need to hang around to do anything else.

That shows clear intent - return a value as soon as the case is matched.

Answer (score 3):

I have much better solution.Please follow below code for above switch statment:

```
$result = 3; // for default case
switch ($foo) {   
    case 1:
      $result = 1;
      break;  
    case 2:
      $result = 2;
      break;    
   default:
      // do nothing
}
return $result;
```

It will not result in any error and code is also fine with concepts.

Comment: Would the default not be better in the switch default? I mean not saying it's "wrong" at all, but the switch has a "default" that you state to "do nothing" with and then you create a new default with the variable. Seems to me it would be cleaner to omit the default variable line and make use of the switch one that exists anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from PHP 8.0 you can use `match` expression:

```
return match ($foo) {
    1 => 1,
    2 => 2,
    default => 3,
};
```

Answer (score -4):

I am not an expert in perfect coding but I think the validator would prefer something like that

```
switch ($foo) {   
    case 1:
      $ret =  1;   
      break;
    case 2:
      $ret = 2;
      break;   
   default:
       $ret = 3

}
return $ret
```

I think using return in case statement to break the flow of the code is not really a best practice. So that's why the validator say there is no break ...

For your question about at category, I don't know ... sorry

Comment: ... perhaps is not the @therefromhere's preference because consumes "no required" attributions... But is a good choice when the `$ret` already exists (is required) for do something in the algorithm.

Comment: "using return in case statement to break the flow of the code is not really a best practice" I have to disagree. First "best practice" is often ambiguous, at the least dependant on the codebase, scenario, etc. But "good practice" is to return early. Here you are setting a variable only to return it later and do nothing else with it. Having `return` in each case negates setting a variable, and it's a lot less code to look at.

Answer (score -15):

From the PHP manual (https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) :

PHP continues to execute the statements until the end of the switch block, or the first time it sees a break statement. If you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case. For example:

```
<?php
switch ($i) {
    case 0:
        echo "i equals 0";
    case 1:
        echo "i equals 1";
    case 2:
        echo "i equals 2";
}
?>
```

Here, if $i is equal to 0, PHP would execute all of the echo statements! If $i is equal to 1, PHP would execute the last two echo statements. You would get the expected behavior ('i equals 2' would be displayed) only if $i is equal to 2. Thus, it is important not to forget break statements (even though you may want to avoid supplying them on purpose under certain circumstances).

Comment: But he's talking about returning from a switch, you're not answering his question

Comment: Not relevant in this case. The `case` block is exited by `return`.

Comment: You are right - i did not read the question properly. sorry for that